# Install NPM packages without Internet

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm very new to npm, and I need to work with NPM packages like express, express-generator, ejs, mysql, etc on a server with no Internet access. This means that simply using `npm install express` will not work since I won't be able to connect to the NPM registry.

Do I go to the GitHub pages of each of the packages and download the zip files (e.g. https://github.com/strongloop/express/archive/master.zip), then do a `npm install ./master.zip`?

What I'm worried is that each of these packages in turn require a ton of other dependencies, which I have to then download individually.

Comment: You should install them elsewhere, then copy the entire `node_modules` folder.

Comment: Doesn't that only work for packages he wants installed locally?  I think he'll need a slightly different strategy for packages that are installed globally, like express-generator.

Comment: What's the difference between packages like express-generator and others? Will it need to connect to the Internet constantly?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is setting up your own private NPM registry. Some of the advantages are:

- NPM will work as it meant to
- You will have a central place inside your company that can serve other developers/CI servers
- It can be used to deploy your private NPM packages
- Governance and security

You will need to deploy the packages you require into the private registry, or if possible have it proxy the public NPM registry.
There are multiple solutions available for setting up a private registry. For example you can use the [npm-registry-couchapp](https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-couchapp) or a Binary repository manager which supports NPM such as [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Repositories) (disclaimer - I'm affiliated).